# Image is not displayed in Spring MVC jsp page

Tags: image, jsp, spring-mvc

I have img on jsp page in Spring MVC app. But can't make the image to display.
The html is

```
<img width="142" height="80" src="portal/resources/${session.Name}/img1t.png" alt="Inspire">
```

Comment: the path is 100% correct, i matched it with one on disk. And the img1t.png exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it!!
the uri should start with /
so it should be

```
<img width="142" height="80" src="/portal/resources/${session.Name}/img1t.png" alt="Inspire">
```